# Exclude packages included in Lambda layers from being packaged with AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pipenv

A number of the dependencies for my Python AWS Lambda function are in Lambda layers, so they do not have to be in the deployment package for the lambda.  I'm using pipenv to manage my dependencies.

To test locally I need the dependencies that are in the layers to be in my Pipfile, but then they also end up in the deployment package.  Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: I am not familiar with pipeenv but I use AWS CDK to build my deployment/zip file.  You can write a CDK that is specific about what it includes or excludes.

Comment: Thank you for posting. Someone who can provide and answer would be helpful and happy to upvote. Is the preffered method to scan the env package for folders that are in the layer and delete them before uploading the zip?

Answer (score 0):

I'm specifically running into this problem using the Amplify CLI. Amplify provides [hooks](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/project/command-hooks/) that can help with this.  In my Pipfile, I placed all of the packages that are in my lambda layers in a "layer-packages" group, and I wrote a pre-push.py hook that, if it detects installed development or layer packages, will uninstall all packages in the pipenv, so that Amplify can start fresh. This cleanup code could be adapted for other deployment systems.

```
import os
import json
import concurrent.futures

def cleanup_pipenv_before_push():
    """
    Iterates through all folders in amplify/backend/function directory
    and uninstalls all packages in the pipenv environment.
    """
    current_working_dir = os.getcwd()
    function_subfolders = [
        f.path for f in os.scandir("amplify/backend/function") if f.is_dir()
    ]

    def cleanup_folder(folder):
        full_path = os.path.join(current_working_dir, folder)
        try:
            with open(os.path.join(full_path, "Pipfile.lock"), "r") as f:
                lockfile = json.load(f)
                if "layer-packages" not in lockfile and "develop" not in lockfile:
                    return
                os.system("cd " + full_path + " && pipenv uninstall --all")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(cleanup_folder, function_subfolders)

    print("Local pipenv environment is cleaned up before push", flush=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cleanup_pipenv_before_push()
```